# I can't type the password in the terminal for the ssh connection

Tags: remote

I'm trying to connect my raspberry pi remotely with ssh connection from my desktop but i am unable to type the password.
Here's the terminal :

```
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.64' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
pi@192.168.0.64's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.0.64's password:
```

Comment: Does the user `pi` has permission to ssh into the device?

Comment: Is the user `pi` present on the system? Has login been disabled for the user `pi`? is password authentication removed from sshd configuration? Are you sure that the password you typed is correct? Have you created a second user, that is able to login?

Comment: The password is NOT echoed to the screen. It's not even masked as `********` so what are you expecting to see when you type in the password? HINT: Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When you type passwords in the terminal, it does not show the characters I do not know why but if you type the password and click enter it should work.

Comment: This is a feature of all Linux based "terminals". Even [Terminals in Macs do the same thing](https://osxdaily.com/2015/02/04/terminal-wont-show-password-when-typed/).